# Syntax of b.startsWith() in basil.js

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, basil.js

I was wondering how the syntax of the b.startsWith() function in basil.js is supposed to look.

I want to check all words of a text to see, if they start with the string 'some' (like 'sometimes', 'something', 'someone', 'somewhere' etc.).

So, I create a variable that passes on every word of my text to the b.startsWith() function.

When I put the string I am searching for in the brackets ( b.startsWith(some) ), then where exactly will I have to put the variable that will be checked if it starts with my 'some'-string?

Comment: Make your own. `indexOf` isn’t a good way to go about that check, and `String#startsWith` is coming in ES6. =) `if (!''.startsWith) { String.prototype.startsWith = function(prefix) { return this.substring(0, prefix.length) === prefix; }; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was indeed an error in our documentation. It's fixed now, thanks for letting us know.

So you can use it as

```
var trueOrFalse = b.startsWith( yourWord, yourSearchToken );
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like their [documentation](http://basiljs.ch/reference/#startsWith) has some errors. It shows the function signature as you have described:

```
b.startsWith(str)
```

But if you look at the [code](https://github.com/basiljs/basil.js/blob/e15bcd608814d5b53c43b9c0047ab5d75393454a/includes/data.js#L648) where the function is defined it looks like this:

```
var startsWith = pub.startsWith = function(str, prefix) {
  return str.indexOf(prefix) === 0;
};
```

The first argument is the string to search through, and the second argument is the string to search for.